# Passing PHP SESSION info into JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass a PHP Session variable into a js function but failing.

Here's what I'm trying. The desired end result is that it reads the correct JSON file based on user logged in details.

Is this even possible?

```
var username = <?=$_SESSION[username]?>;
$('#aboutContent').redactor({ 
    imageGetJson: '/users/'+username+'/gallery/gallery.json'
    }); 
}
```

I've also tried:

```
imageGetJson: '/users/<?=$_SESSION[username]?>/gallery/gallery.json'
```

But still no dice.

**UPDATE - FIXED**

The problem was that this js was in an external file, not in the same file where the session_start is called - so i moved it into the file as opposed to extrenal and all is good now. Using this and works perfectly (don't need to set var username):

```
imageGetJson: '/users/<?=$_SESSION['username']?>/gallery/gallery.json'
```

Comment: serverside session in client side.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not properly quoting the variable. `json_encode()` will take care of this, as well as encoding things properly.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
var username = <?= json_encode($_SESSION['username']) ?>;
```

Comment: That means the session variable isn't set. Does the page contain `session_start()` before it does this?

Comment: Thats what's weird - I call session_start at the top of the header, if i echo $_SESSIO['username'] there it shows but it seems to get lost, probably because this JS is in an external file... frustrating but can't think of another way to do this

Comment: The JS has to be in a file being processed by PHP, so it needs a `.php` extension.

Comment: Each .php file needs to call `server_start()`, unless you're combining them at the server using `include` or `require`.

Comment: Nah it doesn't - I have this is .htaccess - AddType application/x-httpd-php .js - If I include <?php session_start(); ?> in the js file it works ok but causes an error because I've already called it

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of the `.js` file that exhibits this problem?

Comment: I've taken it out of external file and kept it all in one place which has fixed one error but caused another! Will start new question - Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 2):

Lets say the username is John. The line

```
var username = <?=$_SESSION[username]?>;
```

would be echoed to client like this:

```
var username = John;
```

which obviously is not valid Javascript. Try enclosing the username string in quotes:

```
var username = '<?=$_SESSION[username]?>';
```

Comment: What if the username is `O'Brien`?

Comment: This is not thorough example. I'm just pointing at the root of the problem. Proper escaping is another question, isn't it?

Comment: It's part of the same question. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**That is practically not possible.** You can't bring in the server side concepts to client-side.

Comment: Of course you can. The server is creating the page, it can put server variables into it.

Comment: I don't see how that question is relevant. What's the difference between this and doing `echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['fullname'];`?